# Why does =Importrange() cause a #name error in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

`ImportRANGE` returns a `#NAME` error occasionally as it updates itself every 30 mins.

I took a look through [Google Sheet Script Returning #NAME?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56998704/google-sheet-script-returning-name) but there sadly wasn't any solutions. The best guess at a response was about how google sheets loads custom formulas, but since `=IMPORTRANGE()` is a vanilla formula it shouldn't have a problem with that.

My formula is

```
=IMPORTRANGE("URLHERE",(A5&"!"&"D1"))
```

First the URL, then the final section allowing it to request data from a different sheet in the file for every line. I have setup the sheets that contain the source data to be called 1,2,3,4, ect up to 100 to accomodate for this.

I am trying to import data from a different sheet that has a custom script running to import JSON data. The JSON is imported perfectly and once a day a macro will run that updates the JSON values. I have a separate sheet that I don't want to run the script on, so I am using `IMPORTRANGE` to get the data from JSON imports. Every 30 minutes Importrange updates itself and it researches for the values. It would work fine for me for this to be once a day, however, I can't find a way to change that.

Most of the time it has no problems, occasionally it has a problem with a couple of the imports but most are fine. A couple of times it has hit `#NAME` on every single `IMPORTRANGE`.

Comment: how many IMPORTRANGE formulas you have in your sheet?

Comment: I couldn't say exactly, but in the range of 1000-1500.

Comment: Happens to me with only 1 formula with two IMPORTRANGE calls.
Sometimes I fixed it by opening the other spreadsheet and changing the value to force an update. But today I just can't make it work.